# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I evaluate the following limit?

I guess I should do a comparison, but I've got no clue about what to do. Could you give me a hand?

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}
>  + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}\right)$$

Comment: Do you know sandwich thm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each term is smaller than $\frac {1}{n \sqrt {n}}$. There are $n$ terms in the sum. Hence the sum is smaller than $\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}}$. In the limit of $n$ to $\infty$ the sum goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

What about squeezing between $0$ and $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}$ which goes to zero?

Comment: Rather $\frac n{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$.

Comment: @Berci I don't understand.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Berci is saying that the sum is bounded above by $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$, since each summand is bounded above by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$.

Comment: @kobe I see, but do we need that?

Comment: @GregoryGrant it's to apply the squeeze theorem, as you've suggested.

Comment: But $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}\rightarrow0$ so that seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Gregory your inequality is wrong. $n / sqrt(n^3+n^2) > 1 / sqrt(n^3)$

Comment: Sorry I meant $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3}}\rightarrow0$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant you need to correct the answer. (the $n / \sqrt{n^3+n^2}$ to $n / \sqrt{n^3}$)

Answer (score 1):

Let, $$x_k=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}$$

Then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_k=0.$$So, by **Cauchy's first limit theorem**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Easily we can find that, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}.$$for all $k=1,2,...,n$.

Taking summation, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}$$

$$\implies \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}\le \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3}}$$

Then , by **Sandwich theorem** , $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}=0.$$